# What are the spoken Alexa Smart Home error response messages?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

The error interface declares [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-errorresponse.html) "The different ErrorResponse types don't always result in different responses spoken by Alexa." but does not provide the responses for those that do.

What are the responses provided by each error that provides a custom unique response?

Really only interested in V3 directives.  I'm not concerned with V2 backwards compatibility at this point.

Here's what I have so far:

### [Alexa.ErrorResponse](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-errorresponse.html)

*ALREADY_IN_OPERATION:*

- "I'm not quite sure what went wrong."

*BRIDGE_UNREACHABLE:*

- "Sorry, the hub that device DEVICE_NAME is connected to is not responding. Please check it's network connection and power supply."

*ENDPOINT_BUSY:*

- "Sorry, the device DEVICE_NAME is not responding."

*ENDPOINT_LOW_POWER:*

- "By the way, the device's battery is low."

*ENDPOINT_UNREACHABLE:*

- "DEVICE_NAME isn't responding. Please check it's network connection and power supply."

*EXPIRED_AUTHORIZATION_CREDENTIAL:*

- "Sorry, something's wrong. To control DEVICE_NAME try disabling the skill and re-enabling from the Alexa app."

*FIRMWARE_OUT_OF_DATE:*

- "Sorry, DEVICE_NAME has outdated firmware. Please visit the device manufacturer's app to update the firmware."

*HARDWARE_MALFUNCTION:*

- "Sorry, DEVICE_NAME appears to be malfunctioning."

*INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:*

- ?

*INTERNAL_ERROR:*

- "DEVICE_NAME isn't responding."

*INVALID_AUTHORIZATION_CREDENTIAL:*

- "Sorry, something's wrong. To control DEVICE_NAME try disabling the skill and re-enabling from the Alexa app."

*INVALID_DIRECTIVE:*

- "DEVICE_NAME doesn't support that."

*INVALID_VALUE:*

- "That command doesn't work on device DEVICE_NAME."

*NO_SUCH_ENDPOINT:*

- "I couldn't find a device or group named DEVICE_NAME in USERS profile."

*NOT_CALIBRATED:*

- ?

*NOT_SUPPORTED_IN_CURRENT_MODE:*

- Inclusion of `currentDeviceMode`:

  - `COLOR`: "That only works when light is set to a shade of white."
  - `NOT_PROVISIONED`, `OTHER` or `ASLEEP`: "DEVICE_NAME is in a mode that doesn't accept requests. Please change its mode in the app or on the device."
- Exclusion of `currentDeviceMode`:
- "Hm. DEVICE_NAME is not responding."

*NOT_IN_OPERATION:*

- "I'm not quite sure what went wrong."

*POWER_LEVEL_NOT_SUPPORTED:*

- "I'm not quite sure what went wrong."

*RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED:*

- "DEVICE_NAME has reached the maximum number of requests it allows. Please try again later."

*TEMPERATURE_VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE:*

- "I can only set the temperature between MINIMUM and MAXIMUM."

*VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE*

- "That value is out of range for device DEVICE_NAME."

### [Alexa.Cooking.ErrorResponse](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-cooking-errorresponse.html)

*DOOR_OPEN:*

- ?

*DOOR_CLOSED_TOO_LONG:*

- ?

*COOK_DURATION_TOO_LONG:*

- ?

*REMOTE_START_NOT_SUPPORTED:*

- ?

*REMOTE_START_DISABLED:*

- ?

### [Alexa.Video.ErrorResponse](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-video-errorresponse.html)

*ACTION_NOT_PERMITTED_FOR_CONTENT:*

- ?

*CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED:*

- ?

*CONTENT_NOT_RECORDABLE:*

- ?

*NOT_SUBSCRIBED:*

- ?

*RECORDING_EXISTS:*

- ?

*STORAGE_FULL:*

- ?

*TITLE_DISAMBIGUATION_REQUIRED:*

- ?

*TUNER_OCCUPIED:*

- ?

Comment: I think it would be useful to have this list.  However, there are at least two things that might make that difficult.  1) many of the responses may depend on context, and 2) these voice responses may change often.

Comment: Thanks @BillKidwell.  I think (1) will remain rather consistent here because it is these error codes that provide this context.  As for (2), I partially agree with you.  I think their app interface is old enough now that changes to these responses will not happen very often.  Anyway, thanks for the comment!